# Oracle SQL - WHERE [column] IS NULL not returning null value rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm still learning the basics of SQL, and in my class we're using some preset tables with employee names, numbers, jobs, managers, etc. to run different queries.

The query `SELECT MGR FROM EMP;` returns the following results:

| MGR |
| --- |
| - |
| 7839 |
| 7839 |
| 7839 |
| 7698 |
| 7698 |
| 7698 |
| 7698 |
| 7698 |
| 7566 |
| 7902 |
| 7566 |
| 7788 |
| 7782 |

There are 14 records total, 13 with a number (employee number of manager) and 1 that is NULL (company president, therefore no manager).

The query

```
SELECT COUNT(MGR) FROM EMP
WHERE MGR IS NOT NULL;
```

Returns a value of 13, which is correct.

The query

```
SELECT COUNT(MGR) FROM EMP
WHERE MGR IS NULL;
```

returns a value of 0, which is not correct. It should be 1 because there is a single row where the value of MGR is NULL. I checked the SQL Script we used to create and populate the tables and the value as entered is NULL. Can anyone explain why this is returning a 0 for the count of NULL values?

Comment: maybe try COUNT(*) to count the row and not to count a null value

Comment: Using COUNT(*) worked and returned a value of 1, but do you know why? It seems to me like either way should work.

Comment: can you count nothing? the answer is - NO, But you can count records where this field doesn't have any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count(expression)` returns the number of rows where `expression` is not null. If you want the number of *rows* where `mgr` is null, then use:

```
select count(*) from emp
where  mgr is null;
```

which returns 1.

[Oracle SQL Reference: **count** function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/COUNT.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `count (*)`

Your select should look like this:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP WHERE MGR IS NULL;`